# Preserve component state when moving between containers

Tags: reactjs

How can I preserve the state of a component when rendering it in a completely different place, like for example a different container than before, without moving the state out of the component?

Here's an example:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  return <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>{count}</button>;
};

const ContainerA = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
  <div>A:{children}</div>
);
const ContainerB = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
  <div>B: {children}</div>
);

const App = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <ContainerA>{a && <Counter key="counter" />}</ContainerA>
      <ContainerB>{!a && <Counter key="counter" />}</ContainerB>
      <button onClick={() => setA((prev) => !prev)}>Swap</button>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can try it out on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-nd1dlc?file=index.tsx)

Here, I want the state of the counter component not to reset, when pressing "Swap". I've tried always assigning the same key to the component, but that does not work.

Is there another way to do it?

Another example is when always passing the counter component to the same container component, but internally, the container component does not render the passed children at the same place. Like this:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  return <button onClick={() => setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>{count}</button>;
};

const ContainerA = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
  <div>A:{children}</div>
);
const ContainerB = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => (
  <div>B: {children}</div>
);

const Container = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <ContainerA>{a && children}</ContainerA>
      <ContainerB>{!a && children}</ContainerB>
      <button onClick={() => setA((prev) => !prev)}>Swap</button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Counter />
    </Container>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

View it in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7w8pbr?file=index.tsx)

Now, the component does not even move, but still loses state. How to overcome this?

Comment: It's not being "moved", it's being rendered or not--it's a new instance of the component. You'd need to persist its value somewhere (e.g., local storage) and restore it.